# Dealing with overflows when using the '*' operator in IEEE.numeric_std

Tags: vhdl

I am testing out a custom co-processor IP on Xilinx Vivado. When using the `*` operator to perform unsigned multiplication for 2 32-bit vectors, I realized that when the result takes up more than 32-bit, it is not reflected in the more significant 32 bits i.e. more specifically, the upper 32 bits are all 0s and the lower 32 bits display their portion of the result.

```
16449 * 4171239345 gives 613432305
```

I read the `numeric_std` library and it reads:

```
  -- Id: A.15
  function "*" (L, R: UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED;
  -- Result subtype: UNSIGNED((L'LENGTH+R'LENGTH-1) downto 0).
  -- Result: Performs the multiplication operation on two UNSIGNED vectors
  -- that may possibly be of different lengths.
```

Is the `*` operator not suitable for multiplication greater than 32 bits?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's see an MCVE that demonstrates this behaviour. There's no reason the `ieee.numeric_std.unsigned."*"` operator is restricted to 32 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication you are showing appears to be multiplying *integers*. Integers are limited to 32-bit in vhdl, and normally signed. So your second number is too large to represent (in hex: `0xf8a00fb1`). Without any specific code sample, I will assume that even this value won't be interpreted correctly by your simulator.

Numeric_std's `unsigned` values are not limited to any width. Using the `unsigned` type for every value will avoid any confusion. E.g. if you need this to be done on signals, declare:

```
signal a: unsigned(31 downto 0);
signal b: unsigned(31 downto 0);
signal y: unsigned(63 downto 0);
```

Body:

```
a <= x"00004041";
b <= x"f8a00fb1";
y <= a*b;
```

Comment: You're welcome. You may want to add a bit more detail about how you did the multiplication in your question, so others can find it if they have a similar issue.